# Getting VBA Function to auto update when a change is made on sheet - excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function which counts cells of a certain colour:

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
Dim indRefColor As Long
Dim cellCurrent As Range
Dim cntRes As Long

Application.Volatile
cntRes = 0
indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
For Each cellCurrent In rData
    If cellCurrent.Value > 0 Then
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
        cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cellCurrent

CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

My problem is that this doesn't update when changes are made on the sheet (only when F9 is pressed) - I'm new to VBA and would like it to auto update/execute the function when any change happens on the sheet. 
I'm sure there are many ways to do this but a bit stuck on how to actually achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read up on [**`Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) Event (procedure) please.

Comment: I have tried that before posting this. I am new to VBA and couldn't get this working, I'm obviously doing something simple wrong which is why I posted the question.

Comment: The `Application.Volatile` already leads to "update when changes are made on the sheet" which triggers recalculation. Problem is that changing a color is not the kind of changing which triggers recalculation. Only recalculating on every selection change would be possible. But not a good idea in my opinion, at least not for sheets having great amount of formulas.

Comment: So is what I am after not possible? I am aware how that could be an issue for larger/multiple sheets with lots of formulas. However I am working on a single sheet with not many of them, which is why I was wanting this idea.

Comment: @hsquared: it is recommended that "Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" macro is in the "table modul" where the changing occurs. I can not describe it better, sry for my bad english.

Comment: @Rawrplus, @Denyo: Changing a color also will not trigger `Worksheet_Change`. So this is dead end here.

Comment: @AxelRichter If I got the question right, he wants to change the color on the data change of the cell (it's `.Value`), not on color change. I mean, color change upon color change sounds pretty counter-intuitive within itself - unless there is something that's flying over my head here

Comment: @Rawrplus: The function counts the cells in `rData` which are colored the same as `cellRefColor` and returns the count then. And I suspect the returned count shall change if one of the colors in `rData` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the sheet has not as much amount of formulas that recalculating on every selection change leads to an crash, then the following would be possible:

The `Application.Volatile` in your function already leads to "update when changes are made on the sheet" which triggers recalculation. Problem is that changing a color is not the kind of changing which triggers recalculation.

So do a

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Me.Calculate
End Sub
```

into the `SheetN` VBA module.

This leads to recalculating on every selection change in that sheet. And because your function is volatile already this also will be recalculated then.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much! I know it sounds like a odd thing to need practicality wise, but in the instance it is needed for it works perfectly. (its basically needed for people to use who are not that familiar with excel, or computers for that matter, to highlight different exceptions within a month over a few of lists of items.)

Comment: You also could use the CommandBars_OnUpdate event, which could trigger your function, even when you only change your Cell Color. (Will need a bit more coding than Axel's solution)

Comment: @EvR That sounds interesting, Had a brief look around for CommandBars_OnUpdate but have't been able to find much detail on how to use it (That I understand anyway!)

Comment: @hsquared: Don't bother. The [CommandBars.OnUpdate Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/commandbars-onupdate-event-office) triggers every time if some command will be taken. But since you are using the function as a `UDF` in a cell, the only thing you could do is also recalculating the whole sheet then (How would you trigger your function else?). But now on every command instead of on selection change as in my solution. That would lead to nor more recalculations.

Comment: Yes the OnUpdate is an 'even more 'expensive' event as the selectionchange event, but you could exit the event when conditions aren't true. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 2):

CommandBars.OnUpdate Event example:

In a Module: Your function but leave Application.Volatile out of it
In a Class named: "ClsMonitorOnupdate" :

```
 Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objCommandBars As Office.CommandBars
Private rMonitor As Range

Public Property Set Range(ByRef r As Range): Set rMonitor = r: End Property
Public Property Get Range() As Range: Set Range = rMonitor: End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objCommandBars = Application.CommandBars
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objCommandBars = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objCommandBars_OnUpdate()
Dim cl As Range
On Error GoTo einde
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> rMonitor.Parent.Name Then Exit Sub
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Selection, rMonitor) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        For Each cl In Selection
            cl.Dirty
        Next cl
einde:

End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkBook Module:

```
Option Explicit
Private sRanges As String
Private cMonitor As ClsMonitorOnupdate
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Zetaan ActiveSheet
End Sub
Sub Zetuit()
 Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
Sub Zetaan(sht As Worksheet)
    Select Case sht.Name
        Case "Sheet1": sRanges = "A1:A10, B5:C12" 'adjust Sheetnames and monitor-range
        Case "Sheet2": sRanges = "A1:A10"
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
     Set cMonitor = New ClsMonitorOnupdate
    Set cMonitor.Range = Sheets(sht.Name).Range(sRanges)
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Zetaan Sh
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Adjust to Your SheetNames and Range(s) in the Sub Zetaan
(At least the range(s) your function is referring to)

Comment: Well done example. But it should be mentioned that the main approach here is that [Range.Dirty Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-dirty-method-excel) forces a recalculation of the cells which are in `Selection` while `objCommandBars_OnUpdate`. And if this are cells which are referenced in the `UDF` formula (`=CountCellsByColor(A1:A10,B1)` for example) then this formula also will be recalculated - and not needs to be volatile, which is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, yes I also mentioned to leave the application.volatile out. You could also store the interior color of the cells in sRanges and only continu when a change is made to the color. For simplicity left out (and with big ranges to monitor not the quickest solution)